# Handle tasks when activity is stopped in monodevelop

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.android, task, multitasking, xamarin

I am developing an android app using Xamarin and I am having issues using background threads. In their Multitasking demo (http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/MultiThreading) the authors create a task that is suppose to complete a long running process. While this task is running and the orientation is changed I get the following in the output window:

```
05-15 03:12:19.379 E/WindowManager(32764): Activity androidmultithreading.screens.MainScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@423e4aa8 that was originally added here
05-15 03:12:19.379 E/WindowManager(32764): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity androidmultithreading.screens.MainScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@423e4aa8 that was originally added here
```

I cannot find any information on how to handle these tasks when the activity has been killed or restarted. Will a CancellationTokenSource work in this situation?

Comment: I've had some problems with screen orientation too while developing my app. What I did is restrict the app to only use portait mode. This way the app won't recreate itself when the device is rotated. To do this you can use the following : [Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation)].

Comment: Thanks! I tried this as well but I would really like to have both portrait and landscape modes available. I also get the leak when I move from that activity to another and the thread is not finished so just setting the orientation wont help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked the same question on Xamarin's forums and here is the answer:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/14047#Comment_14047